# Can I see my message on the Rabbit Server?

Tags: rabbitmq

Firstly, I'm publishing my json-message to Rabbit.
Then I go to the Rabbit Server.
I open my QUEUE, and I see that my message is here.

[image]

Can I see, how my message looks like here, in Rabbit Server?

---

P.S.: Thanks @IMSoP, I found this!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no...

Queues in RabbitMQ are strictly first-in-first-out, so there's no native facility for "peeking" at messages which are somewhere in the queue. In order to see a message, you have to "consume" it.

You can, however, do so directly in the admin interface you included a screenshot of - at the bottom of the page, there is a "Get messages" heading. If you expand it, you get a few options:

- How many messages you want to look at (remember, you can't choose which ones, they'll always be the ones at the front of the queue).
- Whether to "re-queue" them, so that they'll still be there for other consumers to see. As noted in the pop-up help (the "(?)" link), they will retain their position in the queue but have a "re-delivered" flag, which may cause some consumers to treat them differently (it's the same flag that gets set, for instance, if a consumer crashes while processing a message).